# How to call a trusted function from acroform

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation

I have been looking for an example of how to call a trusted function in acroforms and havent found any. I am trying to build a form for my company that will allow users to click a button and automatically have the form save to a folder on our server (eg: //SERVER1/Forms/). I found this code to test with and placed it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\Javascripts

```
//SaveAs Function1

var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth()+1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
var dateSigned = String(month) + String(day) + String(year);

var mySaveDoc = app.trustedFunction(function(doc,fileNam­e){
app.beginPriv();

var myPath = "C/test/" + fileName + "Agreement " + dateSigned + ".pdf";


//saveAs is the only privileged code that needs to be enclosed
doc.saveAs({cPath: myPath, bCopy: true, bPromptToOverwrite: false});
//doc.close();

app.endPriv();
});
```

Any help on making this work is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the location of the application level script is correct; check whether you have other files in that folder; one of them would be a precompiled one, coming from Adobe.

Now, for calling the trusted function, well…, call it as you would call any other function:

```
mySaveDoc(this, fileName) ;
```

and that should do it.

However, there are a few issues I don't like that much in the application-level script:

The `dateSigned` variable and its bits and pieces will be defined and initialized when the application starts, and then keep their value. In other words, if you keep Reader running all the time, the date will not be updated. To get the current date all the time, you'd have to initialize the `dateSigned` variable within the function. AND, as you are in Acrobat JavaScript, you can use the `util` object for assembling the string.

Your script would then look like this:

```
var mySaveDoc = app.trustedFunction(function(doc, fileName){
app.beginPriv() ;
var dateSigned = util.printd("MMDDYYYY", new Date() ;
var myPath = "/C/test" + filename + "Agreement " + dateSigned + ".pdf" ;
doc.saveAs({cPath: myPath, bCopy: true, bPromptToOverwrite: false}) ;
app.endPriv() ;
}) ;
```

Note that there is als a slash at the beginning of the path (although I may be wrong on that; as I don't have access to a Windows machine, I can not verify it; if someone else would use Acrobat, open any file, and then run `this.path()` from the Console, then he could confirm the slash (or not)).

Comment: Thank you for your help!! Is there a way to format the dateSigned var into YYYYMMDD?

Comment: Absolutely; in fact, you already have the format string (YYYYMMDD). For more about util.scand(), see the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK documentation, downloadable from the Adobe website.